# NSTableView Disabling Particular Cell

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nstableview

I am trying to disable a particular cell in a particular table. I want to be able to do all of this for a whole column in the near future but for now I am trying things out.

tc1 and tc2 represent NSTableColumns whilst tv represents the NSTableView.

The code compiles and run however, the cell at row 2 and table column named "column1" is still enabled. What do I need to do to make it disabled?

Code sample below:

```
-(id)init
{   
self = [super init];
    if (self)
    {
        arr = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        [tc1 setIdentifier:@"colum1"];
        [tc2 setIdentifier:@"colum2"];
        [tv setDelegate:self];
    }
    return (self);
}

- (void)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView willDisplayCell:(id)aCell forTableColumn:(NSTableColumn *)aTableColumn row:(NSInteger)rowIndex
{    
    if([[aTableColumn identifier] isEqualToString:@"column1"])
    {   
        if (rowIndex == 2)    // myindex holds the row index where I need to disable the cells 
        {
            [aCell setEnabled:NO];
        }
    }
    else
    {
        [aCell setEnabled:YES];
    }
}
```

Comment: Remember that the row index starts at 0

Comment: Yes I know. 2 was just an arbitrary number..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was spelling mistake when declaring the identifier. Solved.